# Pandas, how to compare the value from one row with all other rows in the same column and add it as a new row value in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the dataframe;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'words': ['cat','bat','mat','dog']})
```

Now if I want to add a new column `'avg_difference'`

I would like to take the Levenshtein distance of cat with all the other rows, and then add the average as a new column. With the distance of cat and all the other words in its columns as the row value for the new `'avg_distance'` column.

Which can be done using

```
def lev_dist(string_1,string_2):
    '''
    This function has code in my implementation and it returns the dist between string1 and 2.
    '''
    pass
```

For two strings, but how would I go about doing it for rows?

Comment: How would your output df look like? (Use dummy values for the levenshtein)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`jellyfish`](https://github.com/jamesturk/jellyfish)'s [`levenshtein`](https://jamesturk.github.io/jellyfish/functions/#levenshtein-distance) function for that:

```py
df['levenshtein'] = df.assign(tmp=df['words'][0]).drop(0, axis=0).apply(lambda x: jellyfish.levenshtein_distance(x['tmp'], x['words']), axis=1)
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
  words  levenshtein
0   cat          NaN
1   bat          1.0
2   mat          1.0
3   dog          3.0
```